# Measuring actual MySQL query time

Tags: mysql, optimization

How can I measure the execution time of a query without measuring the time it spends waiting for a lock release etc? My only idea was to continuously measure same query and record the fastest time.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Start the profiler with

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

Then execute your Query.

With

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

you see a list of queries the profiler has statistics for. And finally you choose which query to examine with

```
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
```

or whatever number your query has.

What you get is a list where exactly how much time was spent during the query.

More info in the [manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html)

Comment: This is excellent! Do you know if this is slow? i.e. could I add this into my wrapper class, to execute for every query run on my website?

Comment: Never thought about that. Why would you want to do that? Usually this is just for development, I guess. If you want to know which queries are slow have a look in your slow-query-log. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Because queries take different amount of time for different users. slow-query-log seems to count the time it waits for a lock release

Comment: Not really true. Waiting for a lock is also just a symtom for another query being slow. I suggest, pick the queries in your slow-query-log, run them with the profiler to see where they spent so much time. Then, if possible, improve them. Add indexes accordingly, rewrite them, or reduce the data read if the query spends much time on `sending data`. Or whatever it takes to improve performance. I see no point in letting users know, why they have to wait so long. They don't care actually.

Comment: I didn't mean to display the results of the profiling to the users. I just wanted to capture it live and store for my own purposes

Comment: Like I said, that's what the slow-query-log is for. Profiling is also limited to 100 queries max and more importantly enabled per session. It's all in the manual I linked. Also when the same queries take different amount of time for different users that might be a network issue? And I still don't get why. It just makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Mikhail So, how will you proceed? Just curious.

Comment: I'm enabling in-wrapper profiling for a select group of users. All the information from the profiling is saved in a table that I will check out in a week. Any query that has any of the timings over 0.2s will be examined and hopefully fixed up

Comment: @Mikhail Okay. So my answer was helpful after all? Feel free to accept then :)

Comment: anyone has any explanation about the SHOW PROFILE output?

Answer (score 44):

The accepted Answer is becoming invalid...

`SHOW PROFILE[S]` are **deprecated as of MySQL 5.6.7** and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Use the Performance Schema instead; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html

Comment: If Profile gives you anything more useful than "sending data", you win the lottery.

Comment: I am using 5.7.19 and still `show profiles` work properly

Comment: @SivaPraveen - OK, for now it still works, but "... will be removed ..."

Comment: Yeah, it is still in 8.0.  And still mostly useless.

Comment: See also `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.