# Basic connect to database, run query, close connection?

Tags: php

This is a very noob question.

But I'm having an issue that I believe stems from this poorly written database query.  I don't know if I'm not closing the connection or if closing the connection is necessary, but the server is indicating that it's timing out after about 60 seconds and it's causing a high resource usage.  Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this query?

It's just a basic php query that pulls from the database.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //print_r($_POST);

    $example=$_POST['...'];

    if ($job_number=="") { die("Nothing here.");

    }

    $con = mysql_connect("...","...","...");

    if (!$con)

      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("...", $con);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE WHERE job_number='$example' OR email='$example'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == "0") {

    echo
     'Nothing here.';

 exit;
    }

    echo "<div class='sample'>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
        //print_r($row);
        //customer name

        echo "<h2>" . $row['name'] ."</h2>";

        //status

        echo "<p>" . $row['status'] ."</p>";


        }
        echo "</div>";

    }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: The example seems ok. How many rows has your table?

Comment: If the table is really large (millions of rows), does it have indexes on `job_number` and `email`?

Comment: You should move your ```mysql_close($con);``` to just after you get your result if you're not going to query any further. As is, if you exit, you're leaving that open.

Comment: @DivinusVox Unless he has persistent connections enabled, exiting should close the connection.

Comment: @Barmar Just poor form/coding practices. Little reason to hang the close until the end of the codeblock anyway, if it's not going to be used.

Comment: @DivinusVox Maybe, but more typical applications will access the database multiple times. And even if it doesn't, processing the data is usually fast. I never call `mysql_close()` (or its equivalents in mysqli or PDO), and I'm not going to apologize for keeping the database connection open an extra fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest there is a lot about databases you are not understanding.

Databases take time to read. The way they are indexed defines how you need to approach reading them.

Take a look at this [Measuring actual MySQL query time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)

...and a few others.
I have a feeling your database is huge, and possibly badly structured. This is where I refer you to:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database

There is a wealth of information here to clear your question up.