# Total time for long-running MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

What's the easiest way to find out how long it takes to evaluate a long-running MySQL query (longer than 10 minutes)?

The issue is that:

1. When I try to run it from MySQL Workbench, I get a timeout error.
2. When I look at the process list, sometimes the process finishes executing when I'm not looking and I don't know how long the script has taken.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time this may help.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That looks like exactly what I'm looking for! That didn't come up in search, so apologies for the dup.

Comment: maybe you also want to make use off EXPLAIN EXTENDED http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html  and SHOW WARNINGS; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html  to see how the optimizer has seen your query so you can optimize your long running querys