# How do I test the real execution time of a query?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

I get one slow query in Mysql slow query log. Mysql slow query log shows the query need more than 4 seconds to execute.

I run this query in phpmyadmin, it takes 3 seconds. When I run it again, it takes only 0.0002 seconds. I guess there is a DB Cache or something. When I run it in second time, it executing time might not be accurate.

For this kind of situation(executing time is quick), how do I test the real execution time of the query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring actual MySQL query time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purpose only you can use  `SQL_NO_CACHE`

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM `table` .....
```

other way you can set `query_cache_type` to 0 for current session

```
SET SESSION query_cache_type=0;
```

[**SQL_NO_CACHE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html)

[**Query Cache Configuration**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about preventing MySQL from caching the result, you can use the `SQL_NO_CACHE` keyword. (eg: `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM table1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query a little before executing it second time.

So following two queries are regarded as different by the query cache:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
Select * from tbl_name
```

A query cannot be cached if it contains some special functions like CONNECTION_ID(). You can add this function to your query:

```
SELECT *,CONNECTION_ID() FROM tbl_name
```

[How the Query Cache Operates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-operation.html)