# SQL query, which one is more sufficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with three tables:

```
post
    user_id

friendship
    user_id
    friend_id
    status
```

I want to select all posts whose author (user_id) is current_user's friend

I am wondering which one of the following statement is more efficient? (1 is current user's id, 2 is the code for being friend)

1)

```
SELECT * FROM posts
         INNER JOIN friendships AS fs 
         ON fs.user_id=1 AND fs.friend_id=posts.user_id AND fs.status=2;
```

2) query twice

```
SELECT id FROM friendships 
          WHERE user_id = 1 AND status = 2

#   Assuming get (1,2,3)

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3)
```

Can anyone tell me which is faster? Because I do not have enough data, I can not test....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring actual MySQL query time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)

Comment: As a general rule, the fewer round trips to the database, the better, with '1' being optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Join your tables in the same order you would access them as a human:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM friendships f
JOIN posts p ON p.user_id = f.friend_id  
WHERE f.user_id = 1
AND f.status = 2
```

Here an index will be used based on the WHERE clause to find rows in `friendships`, which will then be used to access `posts` via an index.

Make sure there are indexes on `posts.user_id` and `friendships.user_id`.

Comment: But this won't have any effect on performance (compared with option 1), right?

Comment: @Strawberry Although it may be the same, I'm inclined to say it will be better (for sure not worse), because the optimizer can be dense. However, checking the query plan with `EXPLAIN` is the only sure fire way to know. There is always the query execution time too for a basic comparison.