# Is reading/writing to mysql database periodically CPU intensive?

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, cpu-usage

I will be writing a program in Delphi that will be reading and writing to a MySQL database tables on a regular basis like every 5 seconds. Is this going to be CPU intensive? or get to a point where computer will freeze completely? I know reading and writing to and from a hardrive nonstop can freeze everything on your computer. I am not really sure about MySQL database.

Comment: It is unlikely that basic queries running every 5 seconds would freeze the database.  Of course, it is very easy to come up with queries that would be a problem.  Databases can typically handle multiple transactions per second.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I contemplate my queries mostly going to be simple or basic.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: The PC this program will be running on is very current and has plenty of speed (Quad Core CPU) , memory and space.

Comment: Usually, in many databases you hit I/O issues before you get CPU issues unless you have very fast disks and a well designed and configured DB and queries. In modern systems most I/O operatins are offloaded from the CPU - but a lot depends on what HW you run your database engine on and what other concurrent process may be running.

Comment: I think you need better mental model of how computers work. Running a query is basically never cpu bound on the client. It may be on the server end. The reason you might have delays on the client is that thee query is synchronous. You have to wait for the round trip to the server and back to complete. Your app can become unresponsive and not be cpu intensive. Try executing `Sleep(INFINITE)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, David. What if my program and MySQL server are going to be residing and running from the same machine?

Comment: If your app and the MySql server are going to be running on the same machine, surely you can run some tests and answer this yourself, instead of inviting speculation with most of the salient facts missing?

Comment: If you are running client and server on the same machine, why didn't you say so? Why not use embedded db in that case. Will perform better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Databases are designed to handle many transactions frequently, but it really depends on what the queries you are using. A simple SELECT on a couple rows is unlikely to cause an issue, but large scale updates targeting many tables or multiple joins can slow performance. It all depends on what your queries are.

Answer (score 3):

This all depends on the computer and the complexity of the query.

Answer (score 1):

As David has said, it really does depend on the hardware and queries you are processing.

I would suggest measuring the processing time of each query to determine whether the writing processes will be stacking over the other 5 second interval queries.

You can find information on how to measure your MySQL processes [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)