# which query is faster if filter is done in join or using a where clause after join

Tags: mysql, sql

compare these  two queries:....

Query 1

```
SELECT      *
FROM        TableA a
INNER JOIN  TableXRef x
        ON  a.ID = x.TableAID
INNER JOIN  TableB b
        ON  x.TableBID = b.ID
WHERE       a.ID = 1            /* <-- Filter here? */
```

Query 2

```
SELECT      *
FROM        TableA a
INNER JOIN  TableXRef x
        ON  a.ID = x.TableAID
        AND a.ID = 1            /* <-- Or filter here? */
INNER JOIN  TableB b
        ON  x.TableBID = b.ID
```

Comment: you can profile the time each query takes to execute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time

Comment: WIth an `inner join`, the two queries should have the same execution plan, and hence the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter, the same thing should be executed in both cases.

Personally I prefer join conditions only in the ON clause and "filtering" in the WHERE clause.

Comment: It's because the database plans the execution of the query right? (using relational algebra)

Comment: But i think so, the former query will not return any actual matches for a.id other than 1, so the latter syntax (with WHERE) is logically more consistent.