# using python to query mysql how can I return the query runtime

Tags: python, mysql, performance, time

For example if I run a query directly on mysql I see the following

> `mysql> show databases;
>   +-----------------------+
>   | Database              |
>   +-----------------------+
>   | information_schema    |
>   | mysql                 |
>   | performance_schema    |
>   +-----------------------+
>   7 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

I am interested in `7 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Is there a way to get the time specifically.

I know I can get the rows by using
cursor.rowcount.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time

Comment: What is the python command for fetching the high resolution clock?  Use that before and after the query, then subtract.