# Count query execution time in pma

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin when we execute a query

```
Example : SELECT * FROM  `employee_details`
```

it displays execution time like this

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 (92 total, Query took 0.0052 sec)
```

if we are using count()

```
Example : SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM  `employee_details`
```

then i am not able to view any query execution time

How do we get execution time while using count() in phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you cannot see the execution time in PMA as I could do a test and see that time. But in general to get the exact execution time you need to do the following:

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

Then your Query. Then

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

And at the end you pick the one you want to see its execution time.

```
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
```

Here is the answer to [Measuring actual MySQL query time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)

Comment: this was helpful, i tested it in my pma and wrote a detail explanation for this below

Comment: I don't think PMA times can be relied upon. They are often wrong.

Comment: I didn't say it is accurate, I just said it shows execution time in my case for COUNT

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code at the top of your php code:

```
$start_time = microtime(true);

// your code

$execution_time = (microtime(true) - $start_time) / 60;   // In minutes

echo "Total Execution Time: ".$execution_time."\n\n";
```

It will give the total execution time in minutes

Comment: I want this directly in phpmyadmin instead of writing php code.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, in phpmyadmin under 'Run SQL query' panel execute this

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

then second step

```
SHOW PROFILES;
SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM  `employee_details`
```

if you want pma to display execution time then add 'SHOW PROFILES' before your count() query and execute it, this displays execution time

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 (92 total, Query took 0.0052 sec)
```

if you already set your profiling then you can execute second step directly in phpmyadmin under 'Run SQL query' panel

Comment: It's not a good approach to copy and paste answer from someone and submit as your own answer as accept it as the answer for yourself! This was posted by me and accepted as answer before!

Comment: i have added my answer for step wise explanation with reference of your answer, thought that explanation would be helpful for others, previously i marked your answer as helpful, well accepted your answer.