# How to catch 1 row in set (0.01 sec) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get mysql "1 row in set (0.01 sec)", like in the example below?

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6541555 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

[image: How to get the value framed in red? (click this for image)]

Comment: so you want to know how much time did the query take to execute and return values and how many values it returned?

Comment: yes... any ideas ?

Comment: sure. Google for "mysql return number of rows" & "mysql query execution time". you will be surprised of how many results you will find for each question.

Comment: got it... thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring actual MySQL query time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

- SET profiling = 1;
- show profiles;`

  to get duration.

Answer (score -1):

if you using php you can get number of rows affected as follows.

```
$select_1 = $db_connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table");
$num_rows = $select_1->num_rows;
```

Comment: Then you can use 'ROW_COUNT()' in mysql. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: yeah... but how about the duration ?