# Print console output of the run time of a pymysql query

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I am using `pymysql` to execute some sql insertion queries. I am using `LOAD DATA INFILE` and it works fine.

Usually when you run SQL queries it prints the number of rows and the time at the bottom. If it is a `SELECT` query it would print the table before it. I am aware of some third party libraries that help in printing the table. I am looking for a way to print the last line that includes the number of rows and time.

Here is a sample -

```
MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  world_x  JS > shell.options.set('resultFormat','table')
MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  world_x  JS > session.sql("select * from city where countrycode='AUT'")
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| ID   | Name       | CountryCode | District      | Info                    |
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 1523 | Wien       | AUT         | Wien          | {"Population": 1608144} |
| 1524 | Graz       | AUT         | Steiermark    | {"Population": 240967}  |
| 1525 | Linz       | AUT         | North Austria | {"Population": 188022}  |
| 1526 | Salzburg   | AUT         | Salzburg      | {"Population": 144247}  |
| 1527 | Innsbruck  | AUT         | Tiroli        | {"Population": 111752}  |
| 1528 | Klagenfurt | AUT         | Kärnten       | {"Population": 91141}   |
+------+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.0030 sec)
```

I want to print `6 rows in set (0.0030 sec)` using `pymysql`. I have already tried using `EXPLAIN` but that only works with`SELECT` commands. I have tried using `fetchone()`, `fetchall()`, `fetchmany()` with no luck.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time

Answer (score 0):

It is supposedly *deprecated*, but as of MySql 8.0 you can still turn on profiling with:

```
set profiling = 1;
```

But, let's be forward thinking; see [Query Profiling Using Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html)

So, if `conn` is a `pymysql` connection:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
# enable "profiling":
cursor.execute("UPDATE performance_schema.setup_consumers SET ENABLED = 'YES' WHERE NAME LIKE '%events_statements_%'")
cursor.execute("UPDATE performance_schema.setup_consumers SET ENABLED = 'YES' WHERE NAME LIKE '%events_stages_%'")

# execute your query
cursor.execute("select * from city where countrycode='AUT'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# get execution time for last query:
cursor.execute("""SELECT TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT/1000000000000,6) as Duration, SQL_TEXT
                        FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long
                        WHERE SQL_TEXT like '%select * from city where countrycode%'""")
total_time = cursor.fetchone()[0]

# code to print out the rows from your query
n_rows = len(rows) # number of rows returned
# other code to display rows omitted

# then finally:
print(f'{n_rows} row(s) in set ({total_time} sec)')
```